# Disable "Shows Touch On Highlight" on Swipe Gesture Recognizer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a bar with 8 different `UIButton` on it. Each `UIButton` has the "Shows Touch On Highlight" attribute checked. Not all 8 buttons are shown at the same time.

I split them into two groups of 4 `UIButton` and I use the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in order to toggle between the two views.

This works great.

So, here's my problem:

When I swipe and touch one of the buttons I still see the touch highlight animation, even though the button functionality doesn't trigger (since I swipe).

In this case (of swipe) I don't want to see the touch highlight. How can I disable it?

Comment: set your button like self.btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO;

Comment: btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO; Use this property .

Comment: I don't want to disable the highlight - I want to disable it ONLY when the swipe gesture is recognized

Answer (score 1):

Use the property of UIButton `showsTouchWhenHighlighted`.

Example : `self.btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO`

Comment: I don't think he wants to disable the highlight permanently, just when the touch was part of a swipe gesture.

Comment: Scott - that's right - I want to disable the highlight only when the Swipe takes effect

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this issue I've replaced the UIButton with a UILabel and attached a tap handler.
Since the UILabel doesn't have the touch on highlight it doesn't interfere with the swipe.

Here is a code sample:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLabel = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)];
[tapLabel setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapLabel setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapLabel];
titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

It's more a workaround than a solution but it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UIImageView replace to button

here's the example:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiper = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwip:)] autorelease];
[swiperTopL setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:swiper];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapButton = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap:)] autorelease];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapButton];
```

Hope it can help you,
thanks!

Wayne

Comment: I don't understand - how will this help?